# Drop columns in with only NaN values, pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, drop

I have a dataframe where i want to drop every row where `df['Rank'] < 16`, and when i do `df = df['Rank'].where(df['Rank'] < 16)` it gives alot of NaN values (as it should), and then to remove these values i could do `df = df.dropna` ,but the problem is that `df.dropna` will remove rows that have at least one Nan value, and i want to remove rows where all values are Nan.
Please show multiple ways to do it and explain them because i want to learn and not just copy paste code :)

Comment: Is this gives you what you are looking for `df[df['Rank']<16]`

Comment: Check out the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html. It explains pretty clearly how to use dropna.

Comment: To drop rows where all values are `na`, you could use `dropna(how='all')`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an option 'how', so using the [DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) function:

```
df = df.dropna(axis="columns", how="all")
```

or

```
df.dropna(axis="columns", how="all", inplace=True)
```

you will remove the columns with only NA values.